# How to merge the result of two observations (with different type)

Tags: rxjs

Assume I have these two observations:

```
const thread = of({
  thread: {
    name: "Name",
    author: null
  }
})
const author = of({name:"Snoob"})
```

How can i get the merged result of these observations:

```
const threadWithAuthor = .....;
threadWithAuthor.subscribe(it=>console.log(it))
// {
//   thread: {
//     name: "Name",
//     author: { name: "Snoob" }
//   }
// }
```

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do it using `combineLatest`, `pipe`, and `map`:

```
var {of, combineLatest } = require('rxjs')
var { map } = require('rxjs/operators')

var mergeByAuthor = ([t, a]) => {
    var x = Object.assign({}, t)
    x.thread.author = a
    return x
}

var thread = of({
  thread: {
    name: 'Name',
    author: null
  }
})

var author = of({name:'Snoob'})

var threadWithAuthor = combineLatest(thread, author).pipe(
  map(mergeByAuthor)
)

threadWithAuthor.subscribe(x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2)))
```

Output

```
{
    "thread": {
        "name": "Name",
        "author": {
            "name": "Snoob"
        }
    }
}
```